# about the paste0 in variables including space and ()

Tags: r

I have a csv file with variables including space and ().
So I used the paste0 like `attributes <- paste0(df$var1)`.
This gives me "`ab aaa aa ()`" with ` and `df2 %>% select(attributes)` does not work. `names(df2)` is  "ab aaa aa ()" Could you given me some solutions?? I have tons of variables, so I would like to use `select(attributes)`.

Comment: Hi there. Can you please give an example of your data und then your desired output?

Comment: Hi df<-data.frame( var1=c("3-hy_()","vafg (b)","vafg (b3)")) attribute<-paste0(df$var1) df2<-data.frame( 3-hy_()=c(1,2,3,4),vafg (b)=c(1,2,3,4),vafg (b3)=c(1,2,4,6)) df2<-df2%>%select(attribute) In my csv file the variable names in df2 have space and ().

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the leading/laggiing spaces is the issue.  We can wrap with `trimws`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
   select(trimws(attributes))
#                   ab aaa aa ()
#Mazda RX4                 21.0
#Mazda RX4 Wag             21.0
#Datsun 710                22.8
#Hornet 4 Drive            21.4
#Hornet Sportabout         18.7
#Valiant                   18.1
```

#### data

```
attributes <- " ab aaa aa () "
df2 <- head(mtcars)
names(df2)[1] <- "ab aaa aa ()"
```